# Laravel - Validator between:8,11 not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to validate phone numbers

```
$rules = array(
            'phone' => 'numeric|between:8,11',
            'mobile' => 'Required|numeric|between:11,15',
        );
```

and here is the fields

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone', array('class'=>'col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 row control-label label-input-sm')) }}
         <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9  col-lg-10 ">
{{ Form::text('phone', '', array('class'=>'form-control1', 'placeholder'=>'Phone')) }}
     </div>
        </div>
  <div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('mobile', 'Mobile', array('class'=>'col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-2 row control-label label-input-sm')) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9  col-lg-10 ">{{ Form::text('mobile', '', array('class'=>'form-control1', 'placeholder'=>'Mobile')) }}
     </div>
</div>
```

when I write a number with 8 numbers

got

> The phone must be between 8 and 11

whats wrong with my validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, between on a numeric field validates the value of the field to be between two values.

What you want instead is the `digits_between` rule

Comment: thanks one more thing should I leave the field as numeric too?